# How to add a new TFS 2012 work item from external app

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem

I am looking for an example or link to resources that would explain how to add a new work item to TFS 2012 from an external app.  I have read that TFS 2012 has web services that allow third-party apps to interface with it.  I have been researching how to add a new work item and  I have not found any examples about how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Shai's blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/), he has tutorials on how to do pretty much anything with the TFS API.

[This post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/10/06/how-to-create-generic-work-item-migration-for-tfs.aspx) goes through creating work items.